# HTML Form POST re-writing action attribute

Tags: html, forms

I have an HTML form that I'm trying to get to post with part of a query string already inplace, but it keeps re-writing the URL.

```
<form id="mls_form" action="/index.php?option=com_mls&view=mls" method="get">
    <label>MLS#:</label>
    <input type="text" name="mlsnum" />
    <input type="submit" value="Go" />
</form>
```

Output is:

```
http://www.mysite.com/index.php?mlsnum=value
```

It seems really simple, but I don't know why it's re-writing the action attribute.

Comment: Shouldn't the method be "POST" instead of get?

Comment: I need `get` to pull data from the form and push it into the URL.  `POST` wasn't going that.

Comment: If you use `get` then the querystring on the URL in the `action` attribute will be overwritten with the form data - which is exactly what's happening.

Answer (score 2):

Use the POST method rather than the GET method.  The URL parameters will be sent as specified in the `action` attribute, and the form inputs will be sent in the post data. Your server script can then read them each using whatever API is appropriate (in PHP, `$_GET` versus `$_POST`, or find them all in `$_REQUEST`).

Answer (score 1):

If you must use GET you can give the additional parameters as hidden input fields.

```
<form id="mls_form" action="/index.php" method="GET">
    <input type="hidden" name="option" value="com_mls" />
    <input type="hidden" name="view" value="mls" />
    <label>MLS#:</label>
    <input type="text" name="mlsnum" />
    <input type="submit" value="Go" />
</form>
```

Comment: That's what I ended up doing.  Kept forgetting to put `name` in though.